# Why does my code ignore a large chunk of itself?

Tags: c++, function, class, switch-statement, void

hey I've just started on a school project but can't figure out why the code just ignores a large chunk of itself.

(also the code is part of a function inside of "math.h")

ill paste the whole segment here so that debugging it is easier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;
using namespace this_thread;


class math {
private:
    unsigned short pts;

public: 
    unsigned short questAmount;
    char diff;
    short arrEasy[4] = {1, 2, 5, 10}, secondVar, ans, studAns;

    void questProc() {
        start:
        cout << "How hard do you want the questtions to be?" << endl; 
        cout << "(The harder you choose, the larger the numbers you'll have to calculate)" << endl;
        cout << "1) EASY" << endl;
        cout << "2) MEDIUM" << endl;
        cout << "3) HARD" << endl;
        cout << "4) CALCULATOR MODE LOL" << endl << "~> ";
        cin >> diff;

        switch (diff) {
        case '1':
            system("cls");
            cout << "EASY MODE ACTIVATED" << endl;
            break;

        case '2':
            system("cls");
            cout << "MEDIUM MODE ACTIVATED" << endl;
            break;

        case '3':
            system("cls");
            cout << "HARD MODE ACTIVATED" << endl;
            break;

        case '4':
            system("cls");
            cout << "CALCULATOR MODE ACTIVATED" << endl;
            break;

        default:
            system("cls");
            cout << "INPUTED VAL IS EITHER NOT AN INT OR ISN'T IN THE LIST"; //checks only the starting int ignores the rest...
            sleep_for(0.5s); cout << "."; sleep_for(0.5s); cout << "."; sleep_for(0.5s); cout << "."; sleep_for(0.5s);
            break;

            if (diff != 1 && diff != 2 && diff != 3 && diff != 4) { goto start; }
        }

        // The following creates the question according to the set difficulty.
        srand(time(NULL)); // Initializing random seed.
        switch (diff) {
        case 1: // Easy Mode:
            system("cls");
            random_shuffle(&arrEasy[0], &arrEasy[4]); // For first var.
            secondVar = rand() % 10 + 1; // Rand number from 1 to 10 (for second var).
            ans = arrEasy[0] * secondVar;
            cout << arrEasy[0] << " * " << secondVar << " = ?" << endl << "~> ";
            cin >> studAns;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        // The following checks if ans is correct.

        if (studAns == ans) {
            cout << "WELL DONE!";
        }
        else {
            cout << "WRONG, CORRECT ANSWER WAS:" << ans;
        }
    }
};
```

I wanted it to continue on to actually calculate the question and to then check if I was right or not...

here's what I got instead:

```
How hard do you want the questtions to be?
(The harder you choose, the larger the numbers you'll have to calculate)
1) EASY
2) MEDIUM
3) HARD
4) CALCULATOR MODE LOL
~> 1
```

and then:

```
EASY MODE ACTIVATED
WELL DONE!
```

that's all it says, despite all the other things its also supposed to do...
ps. tell me if you need any more info.

Comment: Compare `case '1':` in the first `switch` with `case 1:` in the second `switch`. See the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of type mismatch!
you defined "diff" as a char and use it as such in your switch statement. However, in your second switch statement, you remove the quotes and use it as a number. That causes a char to int conversion according to the ascii table.

[image: ASCII Table]

Look at the decimal field, the number 1 as an int corresponds to a non-printable character that you will rarely see in real life. The character '1' corresponds to 49.

Solution:

```
switch(diff){
case '1':   //notice the quotations
   //rest of code
   break;
}
```

Comment: Side note: While extremely uncommon in the wild these days, non-ASCII systems do exist and the C++ Standard allows them.

Comment: @user4581301 I bit my c  teeth on an EBCDIC system, one that also had 0xffffffff as null

Comment: English is a strange language. In my parts we say "I cut my teeth[,]"and it still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @user4581301 actually I meant to type 'cut', didnt notice till you pointed it out

Answer (score 0):

for this line

```
if (diff != 1 && diff != 2 && diff != 3 && diff != 4) { goto start; }
```

you mean

```
if (diff != '1' && diff != '2' && diff != '3' && diff != '4') { goto start; }
```

given that diff is a typed in char not an int

Comment: Side notes: The `if` statement would be better handled with the `default` case in the `switch`, making this problem go away. The `goto` can be eliminated by moving the collection into a loop in a new function. This function will loop until a good value is provided and then return.

Comment: thanks, though ive had a minor prob getting funictions to work in other functions if thats what youre getting at... could you please explain this further?